# How to determine thumb height with a scrollspy?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make a scrollbar-like scrollspy but there's a problem; it doesn't actually scroll to the bottom of the track because the height of the thumb is not correct (or I think that's why it's not working).

You can see an an example here: http://jsfiddle.net/92zsvhak/5/

```
$(window).on("scroll", function() {
  var scrollPercentage = 100 * $(window).scrollTop() / ($(".container").height() - $(window).height());

  $(".scrollspy > .track > .bar").css("top", scrollPercentage);
});
```

As seen in the jsfiddle, the green bar should be at the bottom of the red track once you have scrolled down to the beginning of the last `.block` element.

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The height of the thumb is correct, but you forgot to make the var `scrollPercentage` an actual percentage (=> a string ending with '%').

That won't fix everything as you still will have to remove the bar height so that the bottom of the bar doesn't scroll outside it's container.

To make it simpler, set the bar height to 20% and remove the twenty percents from the maximum computed scroll amount (we could do it in pixels but then we will need the bar container height, I'll let you do the maths):

```
var scrollPercentage = (80 * $(window).scrollTop() / ($(".container").height() - $(window).height())) + '%';
```

Note we have subtracted 20 to 100 above, and added the '%' sign;

[Working fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/92zsvhak/24/)